# When using search builder to find contacts that are in multiple specific groups (AND, not OR), 0 results returned

Tags: search, search-builder

Let's say you have Group A & Group B, and two contacts, Contact A and Contact B. We want our search to find those contacts who are in both Group A AND Group B.

For example, if Contact A is in Group A only, but Contact B is in both groups, then the result of this search should be 'Contact B'.

Search builder looks like:
Contacts, Group(s) = Group A
Contacts, Group(s) = Group B

Result: no results.

No errors are logged.

We had several groups built on searches of this type, but after updating from 5.6.1 to 5.10.3 these all broke and began returning no results.

I have tested this on the Demo site but could not reproduce - however the demo site is running 5.13.alpha1, so it's not a fair test.

The release notes for 5.11.0 indicate some search fixes, but not anything that would make me assume this would also be resolved. I wasn't able to find anything in  Gitlab about this either. I'd rather not wait for 5.13 to be released so if someone could possibly point me to a specific patch that I could test in the meantime, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Is one group a smart group and the other static?

Comment: It's an attempt to make a smart group, and all of the referenced groups are also smart groups. I've tried multiple tests, and as soon as you add a second smart group to the criteria it stops returning results. I see now that all the groups on the demo site are manual, I am testing again using smart groups and will post back.

Comment: Confirmed that this works with manual or smart groups on the demo site.

Comment: I would definitely update to the latest released version before putting time into this one.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug that got introduced in the 5.10 series which broke these types of searches, i believe there was a patch release maybe 5.10.4 that fixed it but this is the specific fix https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13667/commits/8966cd19d7897bdadc0588cab2c81df140759efc

Comment: Thank you! Client decided to wait a bit before testing this but I will come back to confirm when we get to it.